# Problems accessing the MS Onedrive web application

Tags: linux-mint, web, cloud

I've recently become unable to access the MS Onedrive web app. It was working find until about two weeks ago but now all I get is a general connection error saying that the site can't be reached. "The connection was reset. Try: *Checking the connection. *Checking the proxy and the firewall. ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

I contacted MS support but they were zero help, telling me to go get support from a Linux forum. So...here I am.

I'm running Linux Mint 18 on an old Sony VAIO Duo 11. It works fine at home but not at work (a university), and I can access the web app on the same network with Win & Mac. I have tried turning off the firewall, accessing from a private window, turning off all extensions, and using three different browsers, all to no avail.

To be clear, I'm not trying to use a sync client. I just want to access the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a certificate trust error. If `apt-get upgrade` fails to help, try a recent Mozilla Firefox.

Failing this, you could of course see if you can reach their site using openssl. Something like:

```
openssl s_client -connect remote:443
```

If that establishes a connection you know the network layer is ok. Is your browser configured to use a proxy?

Comment: I upgrade every morning and have the most recent version of Firefox. I've also tried Chrome and Opera but still have the same issue.

Comment: Thank for your help, Ed. I can make a connection using openssl (I see the server certificate) and my browser is not configured for proxy. If it helps, I don't have any issues with other services like Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: Then it seems that the browser's trust layer is not in sync with the onedrive server certificates. Maybe the ca package on Mint needs updating?

Comment: My ca-certificates package is the latest version available.

Comment: That might have revoked the issuer of the onedrive site. Or google may have done that, for example https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/11/02/google_punts_wosign_startcom_from_good_guy_certificate_club/. Another possibility is that the browser version doesn't regard older SSL crypto as secure.

Comment: Well, it must be something funky with my office network because when I use the general university wifi, I can connect to the onedrive web app without any problems. If I ever figure out the issue, I'll let you know what happened. Thank you very much for your help.